# When taking the derivative of the complex logarithm do we need to specify a branch?

Tags: complex-analysis

Fr an assignment I needed to calculate the following integral: $ \oint \frac{dz}{z-1+i}$ where the contour was the vertices of a square (obviously not important) I did this using Cauchy's integral formula $ \oint \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}$ where $ f(z)=1$ and the brute force method.

By Cauchy's integral formula this is simply $2\pi i$ because $f(z)=1$ always.

By the brute force method, the integral boiled down to $log(1)$ which is $ 2\pi ik$ which appears to be a disrepancy. The only thing I can think of is that when integrating $1/z $ I established that I'm on the principle branch.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Any two branches of the complex logarithm differ by a constant. No surprise their derivatives are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $\gamma(t)$ be a paramterized curve, the integral should be something like $\log(\gamma(1)) - \log(\gamma(0))$. The branch of log wont affect this difference. However, $log(\gamma(1))$ needs to be treated as $\lim_{t\to 1}\log(\gamma(t))$, else it passes through the branch locus. If $\gamma(t) = \exp(2\pi i t)$ then $\log(\gamma(t)) = 2\pi i (t+k)$ for $t\in [0,1)$ where $k$ is the choice of log, and then using the limit definition you’ll get the right answer.

Also note it’s not necessary to think about branch cuts to do this integral, see the Direct Methods section of the wiki page for contour integration:

$$\int 1/z dz = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-it} d(e^{it}) = 2\pi i$$